# Проверка на закрытие вкладки

Tags: javascript

Вкладка открывается таким образом:

```
 window.open('/pay_wm?points='+$('#cpoints').val()+'',
 '', 'menubar=yes, location=yes,
 resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes,
 status=yes');
```

Мне нужно как-то проверять, если она закрыта, то выводить `alert(1)`, например. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я могу подсказку дать, а могу и решение. Что выбираете?)

Comment: @lampa, лучше просто подсказать :) Надо же самому делать ^^ Вроде нужно создание нового окна занести в переменную, а потом if(new_window.closed)... Не?

Comment: @lampa, даааа! Я сделал!

Comment: @ModaL ну умеете же, когда хотите :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам отвечаю на свой вопрос. Кому интересно:

```
var new_window = window.open(...);
var new_interval = setInterval(function() {
 if(new_window.closed) {
  alert(1);
  clearInterval(new_interval);
 }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то нужно вешать обработчик на событие **unload**

Comment: @KryDos, не знаю, что там вешать нужно. Ну смотрите такой пример: пользователь кликнул на ссылку и открылась моим кодом новая вкладка. В случае, если он закроет вкладку, то на месте где ссылка, пусть выведется alert(1)

Comment: @ModaL, "на месте где ссылка" - это то место где пользователь нажал на ссылку? Или это та вкладка, которую пользователь закрывает? То есть при закрытии вкладки ему, в этой же вкладке, будет выдаваться alert(1).

Comment: @KryDos, это то место где пользователь нажал на ссылку. Нажал юзер на ссылку - открылась вкладка. Закрыл юзер созданную вкладку, на месте, где юзер нажал на ссылку, должен выскочить alert